# Finish FragmentActivity from static method

Tags: java, android, exception, casting

I'm trying to finish my `class` which extends `FragmentActivity` from a static method:-

```
private static void myFinish(Context context,Activity activity) {
    [some code]
    activity.finish();
}
```

From this method:-

```
private static void remove(Context context) {
        myFinish(context, ((Activity) context).getParent());
}
```

This code `compiles` but gives me an error :-

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: looks like your context comes from the app and not the activity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a simple solution.
Declare:

```
Activity activity;
```

In onCreate:

```
activity = this;
```

then

```
activity.finish();
```

does the work.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to finish your `FragmentActivity` from within one of your Fragments..

This is how that works:

`getActivity().finish();`

If you are in the `FragmentActivity` itself, you can use `finish()`.

Comment: Nope, I get a `The method getActivity() is undefined for the type SmsPopupActivity`. I'm in : `public class SmsPopupActivity extends FragmentActivity{`

Comment: I've already tried it, I get `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method finish() from the type Activity`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. I hope this helps.

```
((Activity)context).finish();
```

Comment: the simple way.  Context context;   then in oncreate :  context = this;

Answer (score 0):

Make an activity EmptyActivity , call an EmptyActivity by Intent , simply finish the EmptyActivity but put android:noHistory="true" in the EmptyActivity in manifest