# call finish() from static method

Tags: android, android-activity, facebook-android-sdk, static

I am using the Facebook Android SDK and want to close my Activity after a user logs in and gets the user object. In practice I am storing parts of it but I want to close the activity regardless.

```
      // make request to the /me API
      Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

        // callback after Graph API response with user object
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
          if (user != null) {
           finish(); // causes errors
          }
        }
      });
```

The IDE error message on `finish()` is: `"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method finish() from the type Activity"`

how to proceed?

Comment: Try `getActivity().finish();` if you have a context, then `context.getActivity.finish()`

Comment: did you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12025698/1218762 ?

Comment: @Rstar worked like a charm

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Create a reference to your activity in onCreate with

```
//onCreate
final Activity activity = this;
```

Then you can use that in your onCompleted callback

```
activity.finish();
```

You might have to make `Activity activity` global.

EDIT 2/26/2014:

Note that calling `finish()` from a static method is probably bad practice. You are telling a specific instance of an `Activity` with it's own lifecycle that it should shut itself down from a static method, something without any lifecycle or state. Ideally you'd call `finish()` from something with a binding to the `Activity`.

Comment: something like this worked! `static Activity activity;` no more errors, we will see what happens I compile :)

Comment: I'm glad, if it works please mark the question as correct so that this no longer remains as "unanswered".

Comment: yes, it worked as intended, I finally compiled it, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

For some, bclymer's method may not work. It didn't on mine, using the latest beta version Android Studio...
Try this...

```
public class myActivity extends Activity {

    public static Activity activity = null;
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myActivity_layout);

        activity = this;
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

from your other activity within the same package, simply ....

```
    // use try catch to avoid errors/warning that may affect the 
    // next method execution
    try {
         myActivity.activity.finish();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
```